# AngularJS - Redirect to another domain from code

Tags: javascript, redirect, angularjs

I've set up one plunker to describe my problem: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XfOoZmCH2ogFi3TJGMEJ?p=preview)

Actually I want to navigate to another page in another domain (added one handler to a button click). But it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

`window.location.href = "http://google.com";` is working but `$location.absUrl` service from AngularJS default is not working.

Answer (score 8):

The `$location` service does not allow to reload the page. [The Angular way to perform a redirection to another domain is to use the `$window` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#page-reload-navigation):

```
$window.location.href = 'http://google.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the $location service allow you only to change the relative path of your web application whether you want to be redirected to another site you have to use window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

You not not defined `ng-app` on you html. And also not wired up your controller on html. See updated fiddle here

http://plnkr.co/edit/pPJcWtLrbQOHDT5mXleK?p=preview